# What kind of Close Combat skill do I need for grab-like moves?

Tags: skills, grapple, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

The description of the [Close Combat](https://www.d20herosrd.com/4-skills#TOC-CLOSE-COMBAT) skill says, in part:

> Close Combat: Unarmed is an option, meaning skill with unarmed strikes
>   like punches and kicks. However, this bonus does not apply to other
>   forms of unarmed combat maneuvers, including, but not limited to,
>   grabbing or tripping.

What skill do we need to do grab-like moves? Close Combat: Grab? Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Unfortunately, I can't provide an example, but that fits exactly the text involved.

Honestly, as a GM, restricting the skill to just Trips or just Grabs seems a little too restrictive to me ([and contradicts prior 2E guidance](http://www.atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?p=194265#p194265)), so I'd probably let a player include a few combat maneuvers, although getting a bonus to all of them also feels a bit odd.

Ultimately, a lot of Close Combat comes down to the GM and how restrictive they feel it is. Even in the same Green Ronin book, you might find one character who has Close Combat on "Blades" and another with "Swords". And personally, I don't see an issue with including unarmed grabs, trips, and disarms in the Unarmed skill.